# How can we get a one to one correspondence between the client request and the server received the requests in jmeter webscoket load test

Tags: websocket, jmeter, load

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNbta.jpg)

The left in the flowing picture are the requests the websocket server got while the right are the requests the jmeter websocket send , I just don't make sure which the request client sent corresponds to the request received by the websocket server.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to correlate Samplers from JMeter with your application logs you can use [Sec-WebSocket-Key header](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.3.1) for the request and [Sec-WebSocket-Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-WebSocket-Accept) for the response.

The headers can be observed in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) if you [enable debug logging for the JMeter WebSocket plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required in order to pick up the changes. This is what you can get:

[image]

Comment: @Dimitri T Thanks for your help , I get the answer following your instructions，but I also find a problem the response data  from the server were sperated by other responses or requests，it's difficult to identify the whole responses